# Create table in databricks

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

Im trying to create a table in databricks with this code:

```sql
USE CATALOG ${catalog};
    
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${personal.schema};
    
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${personal.schema}.${personal.source}_${personal.table};
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${personal.schema}.${personal.source}_${personal.table}
    USING PARQUET
    LOCATION 'abfss://${personal.schema}@${personal.storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/${personal.source}/${personal.table}/'
    OPTIONS(recursiveFileLookup = true);
```

But i get the error: Input path url overlaps with other external tables or volumes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error says that you may already have table or Unity Catalog volume (in preview) that uses the same external location.  You can use [information schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-information-schema) tables (specifically the `tables` table) to check what tables could be overlapping with your location.